# Jquery Lightbox/Modal Difficulties doubles itself onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, thumbnails

I am very new to jQuery and I have a problem with my Gallery Lightbox/Modal.
Each time I click on a thumbnail, the whole modal opens itself again and I don't know where exactly I have to set a reset.
I am pleased to hear your answers.

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $('img').click(function() {
 var image = $(this).attr("src");
 var caption = $(this).attr("alt");

var appear_caption = "<figcaption id=appear_caption onClick='closeImage()'>"+caption+"</figcaption>"
var appear_image = "<div id='appear_image_div' onClick='closeImage()'></div>";
appear_image = appear_image.concat("<img id='appear_image' src='"+image+"'/>");
var thumbnails = $("thumbnails");

    $(".thumbnails").css("zIndex", "100");
    $(".thumbnails").css("display", "flex");
    $('body').append(appear_image);
    $('body').append(appear_caption);
  });
});

 function closeImage() {
 $('#appear_image_div').remove();
 $('#appear_image').remove();
 $('#appear_caption').remove();
 $(".thumbnails").css("display", "none");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call close when you click the image so you remove any previously opened Gallery Lightbox/Modal

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $('img').click(function() {
 closeImage();
 var image = $(this).attr("src");
 var caption = $(this).attr("alt");

var appear_caption = "<figcaption id=appear_caption onClick='closeImage()'>"+caption+"</figcaption>"
var appear_image = "<div id='appear_image_div' onClick='closeImage()'></div>";
appear_image = appear_image.concat("<img id='appear_image' src='"+image+"'/>");
var thumbnails = $("thumbnails");

    $(".thumbnails").css("zIndex", "100");
    $(".thumbnails").css("display", "flex");


    $('body').append(appear_image);
    $('body').append(appear_caption);
  });
});

 function closeImage() {
 $('#appear_image_div').remove();
 $('#appear_image').remove();
 $('#appear_caption').remove();
 $(".thumbnails").css("display", "none");
};
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me alot!